# Save the stream to mp4 files

Tags: debian, streaming, ffmpeg, rtsp, video

How can I keep the flow (protocol rtsp, codec h264) in file (container mp4)? That is, on input an endless stream (with CCTV camera), and the output files in mp4 format size of 5-10 minutes of recording time.

OS: debian, ubuntu
Software: vlc, ffmpeg (avconv)

Currently this scheme is used:

```
cvlc rtsp://admin:admin@10.1.1.1:554/ch1-s1 --sout=file/ts:stream.ts
ffmpeg -i stream.ts -vcodec copy -f mp4 stream.mp4
```

But it can not record video continuously (between restarts vlc is a loss of about 10 seconds of live video)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VLC does not support segmenting the output file. You can try to use directly ffmpeg as it supports output [segmentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment):

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:admin@10.1.1.1:554/ch1-s1 -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 600 -segment_format mp4 "out%03d.mp4"
```

Comment: I would advise that you want to use `-segment_atclocktime 1` if the application is for "CCTV". As this will try to split based on the wall clock and not time since recording began.

Answer (score 0):

it may be helpful to know how to split audio files into 10 minute segments (i.e. many short files from a huge long file, e.g. for car stereo) since avconv man page has not enough explanatory value. Below is a working shell command line to split up the file "interview.mp3". using less parameters (map) did not work here. some audio files require -map 0:0 , watch output hints.

```
avconv -i interview.mp3 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_format mp3 -segment_time 600 "iview%03d.mp3"
```